# Can variables be removed from a CUDD manager?

Tags: binary-decision-diagram, cudd

Could anyone please tell me that is it possible to safely remove variables from the manager in CUDD? For example: I register two variable by `v1 = Cudd_bddNewVar(manager)`; and `v2 = Cudd_bddNewVar(manager)`. Can I remove `v2` from the manager?

Comment: What is the motivation for removing a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not possible to remove a created variable.